# WPF multipage application

Tags: c#, wpf

Ok, so I want to make a multi-page application (17 pages), and I have each page represented by a class. Is it good idea to use static fields in each class so I can easy access them all in any page(class)?

Comment: Could you give an example of what kind of information you would like to share between your classes? Making a few fields static purely to be able to share them feels like a hack.

Comment: Say for example I have a list that collects some values from page 7 and also from page 10 and then all those values are read on page 15

Comment: I think that you should use a model class, in this class you can save the data and then when you load a page, you can access to your model and get all data that you need to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: this is the first idea that comes to mind. I'm sharing it as it might help you continue but there are probably cleaner / better options.

This is a simple example of a class that contains a List of strings. You create an instance of the "sharedClass" and pass it along with the constructor of each of the Page classes.

```
internal class Test : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private ObservableCollection<string> _sharedValues;

        public Test()
        {
            SharedValues = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        }        

        public ObservableCollection<string> SharedValues
        {
            get { return _sharedValues; }
            set
            {
                _sharedValues = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        #region NotifyPropertyChanged

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

The initialization:

```
public void Initalize()
        {
            var sharedModel = new Test();

            Page7 page1 = new Page7(sharedModel);
            Page10 page1 = new Page10(sharedModel);
            Page15 page1 = new Page15(sharedModel);
        }
```